Did I get a fake part or am I interpreting the datasheet wrong?
I got a couple of BST410e2 in a TO220 package from aliexpress (I know, I know).
According to the datasheet, the status output pin is pulled low by a MOSFET.

So, with no external pull-up, there should be no voltage there, however I measure 5.3V even with no pull-up. It goes to 0V when there is an error.
Let's say it's an error in the datasheet (or in my interpretation of it), but additionally the status signal is not the same as the truth table.

The "Open load" is the reverse (L when input L and H when input H) and the "Short circuit to GND" is undefined (the output is 2.9V).
So, do you think it's a fake or the datasheet is wrong?
(Frankly I find the datasheet woefully incomplete, but I hope that it gives the correct, albeit scarce, information).
Edit: the Infineon page I linked to is for the SMD package, but I could find no significant difference in the datasheet for the TO220 package.
Edit 2: this is the schematic of the test circuit I'm using, on the esp32 I'm toggling the output every second, when it's high I see 12V on the output, when it's low 0V.
Edit 3: I removed the wrong schematic, this is the correct one

Edit 4: in the table on page 10 of the datasheet it says that this part (410E2) has an open drain output, but the 410D2 has a cmos output. Could it be that they mixed up the specifications of the two parts? Or is this a remarked 410D2 (but the price is similar, I don't see the gain of the vendor doing that).
This is the output of the 410D2, Vlogic is 5V (from an internal voltage source for the logic taken from Vbb). The 2.6V with a short circuit to GND could be explained by the 12V power supply (a wall wart) reducing its voltage (it actually dips to 3.5V).

Edit 5:
The 412B2 has a cmos output and open load detection with the input low. If it's a remarked part it's probably a 412B2.

An ambiguous data sheet does not mean a fake part but, buying from aliexpress does not mean a non-fake part. So, how can this be answered?

Some times datasheets have mistakes. Sometimes aliexpress parts are not fake.

How did you measure the voltage? Is it possible that there is some high-impedance way to 5.3V? Did you use an oscilloscope to watch the open output?

@thebusybee with a digital multimeter, I don't see 5.3V anywhere else: the supply voltage to the bst is 12.56V, there's an esp32 connected to the breadboard (only GND and one output, the usb that gives power to the esp32 board is supplying 4.76V and I see 3.32V on the onboard regulator output).
I'm wondering if the status pin is actually giving a voltage proportional to the output current (that would explain the 2.6V when there is a short circuit on the output): some other parts in the profet range have an analog status output, but this one is supposed to be digital.

mmh, nope, the parts with a sense output give a current proportional to the output current, not a voltage inversionally proportional to the output current.

Please add your assembly as a schematic. You might want to check the output signal with an oscilloscope, just to make sure. -- What happens if you add a pull-down with some higher resistance, like 1MOhm? -- The 5.3V looks suspicious, like a pull-up to the 12V, limited by the port pin's protective diode.

@thebusybee I'll try to draw a schematic, but it's simple, really: pin 1 to GND, pin 2 (with a 5K resistor, actually 2x10K in parallel) to an esp32 output, pin 3 to 12V, pin 4 to the multimeter and pin 5 to the load (a 220Ohm resistor).
I don't have an oscilloscope, there's no change with a 510K pull-down, with 4.4K the voltage goes down to 4.8V.

Confirm with another type (or range of the same multimeter). If the value changes, it is likely caused by input current of the voltmeter.

@tobalt, same value with two different multimeters (one of those is only autoranging, the other one gives the same value in autorange and with different ranges selected manually)

@tobalt in any case, with an open drain output there should be no voltage at all without a pull-up, right?

@thebusybee see the edit 4 in the post, what do you think?

@Luca An open drain output is a floating (high-impedance) pin when not pulling down. So it may pick up any kind of stray charge/voltage from anywhere. Add the required pull-up resistor to the 3V3 rail, maybe start on the high side like 1MOhm, and see if that rectifies the perceived issue.

@JimmyB actually my first experiment was with the output connected to an esp32 input using the internal pull-up, I disconnected it when I saw it was at 5V (it seems it didn't damage the esp32). Now I'm reluctant to put a pull-up to the 3.3v line.

If I had to choose the more reliable source, I'd give Infineon the vote. Chinese products from dealers like Aliexpress tend to be faked or erroneous too often. The chip (as the date of the data sheets shows) is more than 10 years old. If the data sheet had an error, you would certainly find errata or similar. -- So, what kind of answer do you expect? -- Did you contact Infineon? -- Please consider to crosscheck with a device from a trusty source.

@JimmyB  I put a 510K pull-up to the 3.3V rail, no change.

@thebusybee you're most probably right (though I have personal reasons to doubt anything siemens says). This is just a one-off project so I don't have a reliable part to cross-check. If it's just a remarked 410D2 I could use it, I can just put a resistive divider to adapt it to 3.3V and be done with it, the problem is if it's a completely fake part and fails in some other unexpected way. I posted a message on the infineon forum let's see if I get some answer there.

@Luca "no voltage" is an ill-defined expectation. There cannot be no voltage. If you expect a value (e.g. 0), then that would be a voltage of 0. Rather an open drain's voltage is better said to be undefined, i.e. the draining FET has no control over it. It could be anything, including 0V, or 5.3V.

@tobalt sure, but no matter what I try (adding a pull-up, adding a pull-down) nothing changes, so I'm almost sure it's not an open drain output but a cmos output. I think it's either a BTS412B2 or a BTS410H2, since, not only they have a cmos output, but they detect an open load with the input L and not H like the rest of the parts, and that matches what I'm getting with this part.

oops, the BTS410H2 has an open drain output, it can only be a BTS412B2 (or a fake)

Assume that there are no genuine parts on AliExpress. That will save you a lot of grief. That assumption is so close to reality that you shouldn't waste your time chasing pennies while wasting hours of your time.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica I never bought components on aliexpress before but I bought plenty of modules, arduinos, esps and they all worked as advertised. Besides, as I said in other comments, I don't want/cannot deal with smd parts, the only suitable (for me) through hole parts are discontinued and only available through unofficial channels, for current parts buying directly from infineon is almost as cheap as on aliexpress. Now, if you knew about a current, through hole, part with similar specs (2A nominal, protection, digital interface) and you told me, that would be a useful contribution.

As you can see in my last edit, the part is probably a remarked BTS412B2 (or a fake).
Aliexpress issued a refund (in an automated manner, the refund came a couple of seconds after I requested it, they didn't even ask me to return the parts).

Unfortunately, they don't refund lost time and nerves ;)

@tobalt sure, but I had to test the parts anyway even if I was sure they were 100% genuine and this is just a hobby anyway, so I see the glass half full ;-)
